# Name of this trivially simple clustering algorithm

Tags: clustering

Is there a name for the following (extremely simple) threshold-based clustering algorithm?

It does a pass over the data and creates a new cluster when no previous cluster is within a given distance threshold. Otherwise it assigns the point to the first close-enough cluster.

It's good enough if the data is already very well grouped and the within-cluster distances are only due to some tiny noise.

```py
def cluster(data_points, threshold):
    cluster_prototypes = []
    labels = []
    for p in data_points:
        label = None
        for i, c in enumerate(cluster_prototypes):
            if distance(p, c) < threshold:
                label = i
                break
        if label is None:
            label = len(cluster_prototypes)
            cluster_prototypes.append(p)
        labels.append(label)
    return labels
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a trivial reformulation of Leader clustering to me.

An unlabeled point begins a new cluster, and all neighbors within a radius r are labeled. Repeat until everything is labeled.

Comment: This seems like the nub of a decent idea. But it would be *much* more susceptible to the initial seed than k-means is. You would get very different results based on which point is labeled first w/i the data space. Is there any way to pick the right starting point or make the algorithm more robust to a poor starting point?

Comment: Thank you, it is indeed called "Leader clustering" (as in https://github.com/talegari/aleader).

Comment: @gung well, they differ by at most the radius r in distance to the representative, so this *can* work as data reduction / quantization technique like k-means with large k. I am a bit reluctant to call it a clustering, as I don't see a notion of "structure discovery" in this method. But it is in the Hartigan clustering book of 1975 if I am not mistaken.

Comment: If I understand the algorithm correctly, consider a case with 3 points in a line w/ distances just less than the radius. If the 1st point considered is the near end, the center would be w/i the radius & would be grouped w/ it, but the last point wouldn't (this 2 points in cluster 1, & 1 point in cluster 2).  If the 1st point considered were the far end, you'd get 1 pattern in cluster 1, and 2 points in cluster 2.  OTOH, if the middle point were the 1st considered, both the near & far ends would be grouped w/ it, leading to 1 cluster w/ 3 patterns. That seems pretty unstable to me.

Comment: Many clustering algorithms can have such instabilities, HAC with average linkage on (1,2,3) for example. I agree that Leader is worse though. But what I'd be more concerned is what to use it for. What is the semantics of the result, what conclusions can you draw from it? I don't think it gives a lot of insight into the data (I'd argue a random sample is better). And if you want to reduce the data size there are better approaches IMHO.

Comment: @HasQUIT--Anony-Mousse I'd say it's useful as a final step in a larger procedure, after some other clustering algorithm has brought the points extremely close together but not quite equal. For example, at the end of mean-shift (arguably still part of mean-shift). Other practical (not stats or science) uses are when you know that the task is trivial: some points are just really close together, while some are very far and there's no danger of confusion, you just want to do a pass over the data and pick out these trivial groups. Or in ad-hoc data cleaning with manual checking.

Answer (score 0):

It's slightly idffernet from k-means but instead of fixing the number of clusters at the beginning, you specify this rule :

> creates a new cluster when no previous cluster is within a given distance threshold

which is not robust because the value of this threshold is fixed at the beginning. Moreover, depending on the initialization, it can change a lot the final classification ie if you shuffle your data, it won't be the same...

To reach the same goal, you should use the [Elbow method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elbow_method_(clustering)) that specifies the optimal number of clusters...

Hope it helps !